# How to save and load object line by line in binary search tree java

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have problems when saving all my employee from tree to file and then load it when run the program. I don't know there're anyway to save all data of my object from the tree to file and load it to the tree again. I have tried the save function like this and my txt output file have all the product in line such as. If there anyway to create binary tree from my txt output file.

```
1-Jack-0901494996
2-Maria-194889201
```

## Write to file function

```
public void write(PrintStream output) {
          write(root, "", output);

    }

     private void write(Node root, String code, PrintStream output) {
            if(root != null) {
                if(root.left == null && root.right == null) {
                    write(root.left, code, output);
                    write(root.right, code, output);

                }
                output.println(root.getData() + "\n");
                write(root.left, code, output);
                write(root.right, code, output);
                       // recursive-case 

            }
        }
```

## And how i call it

```
  BST bst = new BST();
    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("D:/emp1.txt"));
                    bst.write(output);
```

## My BST class

```
  class BST
     {

         private Node root;
         public BST()
         {
             root = null;    
         }

        public void insert(Employee emp)
         {
             root = insert(root, emp);
         }

         private Node insert(Node node, Employee emp)
         {
             if (node == null)
                 node = new Node(emp);
             else
             {
                 if (emp.getccode() <= node.getccode())
                     node.left = insert(node.left, emp);
                 else
                     node.right = insert(node.right, emp);
             }
             return node;
         }
    }
```

And my simply class employee

```
class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>, Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        int ccode;
        String cus_name;
        String  phone;


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return ccode + "-" + cus_name + "-" + phone + "|";
         }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only thing missing is parsing the data in your txt file into your BST. Since you already implemented the insert function, all you need to do is read the document line by line and convert it into an Employee object like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Employee> employees = read("employees.txt");

    BST bst = new BST();
    for(Employee e : employees){
        bst.insert(e);
    }

}

public static List<Employee> read(String file) {
    try {
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null ){
            String[] arr = line.split("-");
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.ccode = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
            emp.cus_name = arr[1];
            emp.phone = arr[2];
            employees.add(emp);
        }
        return employees;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestMusic.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help but there're any other ways that didn't use array list in this situation. My request is not using array list or linked list. I can just use array.

Comment: @T3King the best solution would be to convert the array list into an array. Since an array is always fixed, there is no way of knowing how many lines you need before parsing a file.